# Why does the curl of a function provide this particular amount of information?

Tags: electromagnetism, vector-fields

In a classical electrodynamics textbook (Griffiths), it is mentioned that even though the electric field function, $E:\mathbb{R}^{3}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{3}$, is a (3D) vector valued function, the amount of information needed to fully describe it is equivalent to the amount needed to describe a scalar valued function, and this is because it is the gradient of an electric potential function, $U:\mathbb{R}^{3}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and so is completely determined by it. The author goes on to explains that this is so because $E$ has the property that **its curl is zero evevrywhere**, and this is what restricts the freedom in determining $E$ (and what enables it to be the gradient of a scalar function in the first place).

> This is all fine (and fun), but I find myself unable to answer the question: why does the imposition of zero curl provide an amount of information exactly equivalent to **two** scalar-valued functions (no more, no less)?

An example of the sort of reasoning that leads me to other conclusions: since zero curl is equivalent to equating three pairs of partial derivatives ($\partial E_{x}/\partial y = \partial E_{y}/\partial x$ and so on), leaving 6 out of 9 partial derivatives "free", it seems that "one third of the amount of information" required to describe $E$ has been taken up, as opposed "two thirds"...
I am of course assuming here that the first order partial derivatives **determine the behavior of the function** (perhaps up to a constant as in the 1D case?), and that these partial derivatives are **independent of each other** and thus provide equal amounts of information. Is either of these assumptions wrong? Is my whole reasoning off?

Any insight into this question and a possible answer would be appreciated.

Edit: I am not asking why (or when) a vector field having zero curl is equivalent to it being a gradient of some scalar field. I am asking about the amount of information we get about a vector field when we determine its curl.